# How to override name.phtml for order invoice view in admin panel : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, invoice, sales

I am trying to override `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml` to add some custom value under sku.
I created a module (it is installed properly). 
In this I have created `sales_order_invoice_view.xml` at `app/code/Custom/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml`. In this I wrote:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
    <referenceContainer name="left">            
        <referenceBlock name="invoice_items">
            <block class="Custom\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name\Seller" name="column_name" template="Custom_Sales::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Next I created `app/code/Custom/Sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml`. In this I just copied code from original file and added a text like:

```
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
<div id="order_item_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>_title"
class="product-title">
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
</div>

<div class="product-sku-block">
<span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('SKU') ?>:</span> <?= implode('<br />', $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?>

<!-- My Custom text here -->
CUSTOM TEXT: asdfasdf;
<!-- end -->
</div>

<?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
<dl class="item-options">
<?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
<dt><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['label'] ?>:</dt>
<dd>
<?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['value'] ?><?php if(isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid() ?>"> ...</span><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id = 'id' . uniqid() ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
<script>
require(['prototype'], function() {
$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();
$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').show();});
$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').hide();});
$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();});
$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').show();});
 });
 </script>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </dd>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </dl>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
```

Please Some one tell me what mistake I have done here ?

Comment: What errors exactly appeared ?

Comment: Did you try module <module name="Magento_Sales"/> in di.xml

Comment: i am not getting any error. but my custom code is not getting displayed there.
I have added.<module name="Magento_Sales"/> in module.xml. do i need to add it in di.xml??

Comment: also if i add 
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Custom_Sales::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/> in core sales_order_view.xml. it shows my custom code.exactly how i need

Comment: It worked after cleaning cache.

Comment: Greate, You must clear cache, when edit in di.xml file and do upgrade. is that after add <module name="Magento_Sales"/> in di.xml ?

Comment: No, I was trying to call my .phtml file in various ways like the one i have done in my code above in sales_order_invoice_view.xml and the way  Aasim Goriya suggested and many more. but was not clearing cache. We should try clearing cache if our changes are not appearing on frntend  after making change in xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Try following way:

**Custom/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom_Sales::items/column/name.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copy original file into following location:

```
Custom/Sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't display anything.i get blank space there.

Comment: can you please check with uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); in `app/bootstrap.php`, you will get error message if any

Comment: I have already enabled all error logs.
there is no error on log files, or on screen it just give me blank space like in 
https://screenshots.firefox.com/hk0iAHNhvtsH08QD/127.0.0.1
it is the page while creating invoice in magnto2.2.2 admin panel.

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/hk0iAHNhvtsH08QD/127.0.0.1-  please see "items invoiced" section

Comment: have you add contents in name.phtml ?

Comment: yes, i have given the same content in my question posted above.

Comment: as i have replied @Jsparo30 . If i call my block using core .xml file it renderes my custom file . So i think there is some problem with the way i have given reference in my xml file.

Comment: Please accept my and if you think its helpful to you. Thanks :)